# Form API: completely custom tableselect?

Tags: forms

I need a table that'll have some rows tableselect and some not, also it I should be able to set properties on specific *rows* and *cells*, not just inputs. Row can have 1 or many values.

Is that possible with Form API? I've tried to just stuff self-generated HTML into `markup`, but that didn't work out (in submission I don't see values).

Any ideas how to do that?

**UPD:** An example of what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/rLwpW/1/

Comment: did you try this example  

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#tableselect

Comment: yes, I did. I've digged into `includes/form.inc` and found there `theme_tableselect` and I don't see any way to disable the checkbox for particular row or add an attribute to `td`/`tr`